# How to convert string of Arrays into an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want this "size": "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]", to Look like this [6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
When I'm outputting a product.size it is coming like, Size - [6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18] .
But i want it like this, Size - 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 .
product is an object which has many "key":"values" and "size": "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]" is one of them.
I have already tried JSON.parse(product.size)
[You can see in the image in the details of the card where it is showing size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjiCY.jpg)

Comment: The `JSON.parse` approach already points in the right direction. But in order to not fail with parsing a wrong JSON syntax one needs to replace all occurrences of `],[` within the string value with just `,` ... `JSON.parse(product.size.replace((/\]\s*,\s*\[/g), ', '))`

Comment: @PeterSeliger it worked like this Size - [ 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 ] thanks.. but I don't want even brackets and comma.  I want  Size - 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 .

Comment: @ShahabDadKhan ... either one `join`s the parsed array items or one directly `match`es every digit character sequence and `join`s this result too ... `product.size.match(/\d+/g).join(' ')` ... and check all the code examples beneath, meanwhile I was providing some approaches as well.

Comment: @PeterSeliger thank you for asking me out. Actually, I do not know how to use Regex but your answer helped me as I copy-pasted what you provided me & it worked, there isn't any question left. I will learn how to use Regex. My reputations are less than 15 otherwise I would have voted your answer up at the very first moment. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ShahabDadKhan ... I did not ask for voting since everyone can see your reputation score. I honestly did ask for feedback, cause after everyone's effort, at least I don't like to be left without response. It is as if the OP just disappears and one does not know which answer actually was helpful or which answer was raising even more questions. And of cause there is also an acceptance link/button to any provided answer which the OP is free to press/click for the answer which was most helpful to the OP.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes brother I also believe you help me not for a vote, your help was sincere & I'm thankful for that. Also, I will keep in mind to pick the answer which worked for me & responding back. I'm new to the StackOverflow community, that is why I didn't know this thing but now I know thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regex to capture the numeric strings from your object's value then convert them to numbers

```js
let obj = {
    "size": "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]"
}

let result = obj.size.match(/\d+/g)
                     .map(e => parseInt(e))
                     
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The OP apparently wants a plain string, thus your matching digits approach turns out to be the most straightforward one, cause it then can be simplified to ... `product.size.match(/\d+/g).join(' ')`

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks i just wanted to help him.

Answer (score 1):

You've to flatten this array.

```
var size = [[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]];
var sizeArray = [].concat.apply([], size);

console.log(sizeArray);
```

UPDATE:

it would be good if you convert your string into array first like:

```js
 var strArray = "[2],[4]"
    const arrayFromString = JSON.parse(`[${strArray}]`);
    var sizeArray = [].concat.apply([], arrayFromString);
    
    console.log(sizeArray);
```

Comment: The OP has a stringified array of arrays.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yeah... just noticed and updated my answer.

Comment: @PeterSeliger its done, and thanks for support :)

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> *"The `JSON.parse` approach already points in the right direction. But in order to not fail with parsing a wrong JSON syntax one needs to replace all occurrences of `],[` within the string value with just `,` ... `JSON.parse(product.size.replace((/\]\s*,\s*\[/g), ', '))`"*.

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method also consumes [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which in case of the OP should look like this ... `/\]\s*,\s*\[/g` ... and reads like that ...

- match a closing bracket ... `\]` (needs to be escaped)
- match an optional whitespace(-sequence) ... `\s*`
- match a comma character ... `,`
- match an optional whitespace(-sequence) ... `\s*`
- match an opening bracket ... `\[` (needs to be escaped)
- `/ ... /g` the entire pattern has to match globally (matches every occurrence)

```js
const product = { size: '[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]' };

console.log(
  JSON.parse(
    product.size.replace((/\]\s*,\s*\[/g), ', ')
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *"@PeterSeliger it worked like this Size - [ 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 ] thanks.. but I don't want even brackets and comma. I want Size - 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 . – Shahab Dad Khan"*

In this case, one just needs to [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) all the items of the parsed array ...

```js
const product = { size: '[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]' };

console.log(
  JSON.parse(
    product.size.replace((/\]\s*,\s*\[/g), ', ')
  ).join(' ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... or one builds upon *Alan Omar*'s idea of [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)ing all digit characters ...

```js
const product = { size: '[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]' };

console.log(
  product.size.match(/\d+/g).join(' ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

So it is as simple as using `replaceAll` with `JSON.parse`:

```js
let str = "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]";
//JSON.parse(str.replaceAll('],[', ','));
let arr = JSON.parse(str.replace((/\]\s?,\s?\[/g), ','));
console.log(arr);
// [6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Thanks [peter seliger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627243/peter-seliger) for his note about
the case where there are additional whitespaces somewhere in between `],[`. for that case use regular expression with `\s` which means space and `?` mean if there is space or not. and flag `/g/` to replace all this matched with a comma `,`.

Comment: This approach fails as soon as there are additional whitespaces somewhere in between `],[`.

Comment: Good note, I update the answer to deal with this case!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to make like this but you can follow this.

```
let data = {
    "size": "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]"
}
let string = "["+data.size+"]"
console.log(JSON.parse(string).join(',')) // will output "6,8,10,12,14,16,18"
console.log("["+JSON.parse(string).join(',')+"]") // will output " [6,8,10,12,14,16,18]"
```

Answer (score -1):

Traverse once:

```js
let size = "[6],[8],[10],[12],[14],[16],[18]";

let numArray=[];
let temp='';
for (let i=0;i<size.length;i++) {
  let c = size[i];
  if (c===',' || i===size.length-1) {
    if (temp) {
      numArray.push(parseInt(temp));
      temp = '';
    }
  } else if (parseInt(c) || c==='0') {
    temp+=c;
  }
}

console.log(numArray);
```

O(n)